# PHP zeropad (sprintf) AND number_format total

Tags: php

I have a `$total` with a value of `1400` which I'm trying to echo as `1,400.00` however `sprintf` and `number_format` refuse to cooperate with each other. How do I properly format the `$total` to `echo` as `1,400.00`?

```
<?php
$total = 1400;
echo sprintf('%0.2f',$total);
//'1400.00'

echo number_format($total);
//'1,400'

echo sprintf('%0.2f',number_format($total_grand));
//'1.00'

echo number_format(sprintf('%0.2f',$total));
//'1,400'
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should suffice:

```
$total = 1400;        
echo number_format($total,2);
```

This will output:

```
1,400.00
```

See: [number_format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)